# Cómo ejecutar dos aplicaciones web que se comuniquen con el mismo puerto pero en diferente sitio en IIS

Tags: asp, iis

Estoy tratando de ejecutar usando el iis.
una app web que se comunica con otra app tipo API que solo devuelve un json
El problema es que son distintos sitios web y obviamente distintos puertos al consultar a la API
Agarra el puerto de la app donde tengo la vista y por eso me da error .
La api está en el:80 y la app con vistas está en el puerto :8080
Al consultar me da error 404

Como podría solucionarlo?
De antemano gracias.

Comment: tienes que poner el puerto al consultar la api (www.sitio.com:80) . Para más detalle debes poner un ejemplo concreto de consulta a la api

Comment: por lo general se define un subdominio o una ruta para el api y se monta un proxy reverso, dejas el sitio/app en el puerto 80 y el api pasará a estar en un subdominio o carpeta. para IIS fijate si esto te sirve https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world/ba-p/846222

Comment: Probaré eso del reverse próximo